# Connect to a Specific Wi-Fi access point

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking

I have a old D-link DWA-160 Xtreme. Whenever I try to install the software to control the wifi adapter, it just won't work in windows 8. I tried every possible tricks and I suspect it's just the compatibility on windows 8. (It works on my windows 7 when I dual boot)

Anyways, back to my problem. Windows 8 in-built interface for connecting in wifi is very limited, it will only show you the strongest wifi signal even there are multiple number of the same SSID in the area. I'm in the university.

Whenever windows connected to a wifi access point, it defaults to a 802.11g type @ 2.4ghz. But when I use WifiInfoView, it detects 5GHZ access points using 802.11n and 802.11a and that's to be expected since the adapter is capable of connecting to both 2.4ghz and 5ghz

Now I want to connect to the 5Ghz speicifcally, I tried going to the D-link driver properties in windows, go to advanced and disabled Wireless mode 2.4Ghz. But when windows tried to scan and connect on the access point, still the same, it defaults to 2.4Ghz 802.11g. Is there any software that can replace what the incompatible D-link software is doing?

I really don't want to switch to windows 7 just to use the 5Ghz network in my university.

Comment: According to ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DWA-160/REVB/DWA-160_REVB2_RELEASENOTES_2.42_EN.PDF there are compatible drivers for Windows 8 on the Dlink website (at least for the rev B adapter). See http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-160

Comment: I'll try if the B driver works, but I got the A2 version so this is just gonna be a punch in the dark